# Use LINQ to check if all values are "0"?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple datatable :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("myTable");
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("John_a", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("Paul_a", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("George_b", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("Ringo_b", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("Yoko_a", typeof (int));
```

it has one row with data :

```
DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r["id"] = 1;
r["John_a"] = 0;
r["Paul_a"] = 0;
r["George_b"] =4;
r["Ringo_b"] = 2;
r["Yoko_a"] =10;

dt.Rows.Add(r);
```

I need to get a `bool` answer ( true) only  if :

All Values on  columns whose name *ends* with `"_a"` has value `0`

So here  , I should get `False`. why ?

Becuase

```
John_a has 0
Paul_a has 0
```

but

`"Yoko_a"` (which also ends with `"_a"`) doesn't have "0" but another number.

What have i tried :

```
var t =
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  .Where(c => c.ColumnName.ToLower().EndsWith("_a")
                              && row.Field<int>(c.ColumnName) == 0
                        )
                    ).Any();
```

but It returns `True`....

What am I missing?

Comment: .Any() means 'if any of the following return true, then the entire result is true'. You want .All().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name suggests, use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
bool allZero = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.ColumnName.EndsWith("_a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .All(c => dt.AsEnumerable().All(r => r.Field<int>(c) == 0));
```

Note that this approach also check all rows of the `DataTable`, i've asumed that this is what you want. `Enumerable.All` returns `false` as soon as one comparison returned `false`.

**Edit**

> I need only the first row to be checked.

Then it's even easier:

```
bool allZero = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.ColumnName.EndsWith("_a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .All(c => dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(c) == 0);
```

Comment: I need only the first row to be checked.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If there is only one row, then it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes but it would be great to assure only the first row is checked.( again , this solution is fine)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Edited my answer. Replace `dt.Rows[0]` with the `DataRow` of your choice.

Comment: I didnt know this overload `r.Field<int>(c)` (where c is not string name)

Comment: The DataColumn-overload is useful to prevent typos and is also a little bit more efficient.